# urls error in django 1.11.x upgrade to 2.0

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I am migrating my project from django 1.11.x to 2.0. I have everything going well till I got to urls. I happen to have an import like this

`from cashondelivery.dashboard.app import application as cod_app`

and I have my url pattern as

```
url(r'^dashboard/cod/', include(cod_app.urls)),
```

but I got the following error in my terminal

```
url(r'^dashboard/cod/', include(cod_app.urls)),
  File ".../dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 27, in include
    'provide the namespace argument to include() instead.' % len(arg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Passing a 3-tuple to include() is not supported. Pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name, and provide the namespace argument to include() instead.
```

I would really appreciate a fix.

**cashondelivery->dashboard->app**

```
import django
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

from oscar.core.application import Application

from . import views


class CashOnDeliveryDashboardApplication(Application):
    name = None
    default_permissions = ['is_staff', ]

    list_view = views.TransactionListView
    detail_view = views.TransactionDetailView

    def get_urls(self):
        urlpatterns = [
            url(r'^transactions/$', self.list_view.as_view(),
                name='cashondelivery-transaction-list'),
            url(r'^transactions/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', self.detail_view.as_view(),
                name='cashondelivery-transaction-detail'),
        ]

        if django.VERSION[:2] < (1, 8):
            from django.conf.urls import patterns

            urlpatterns = patterns('', *urlpatterns)

        return self.post_process_urls(urlpatterns)


application = CashOnDeliveryDashboardApplication()
```

Comment: can you post the code for cod_app.urls?

Comment: i have the updated request

Comment: If you're upgrading from Django 1.11 to Django 2.0, you can simplify the code by removing the `if django.VERSION[:2] < (1, 8):` block.

Comment: I got the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to drop the `include()` and just pass the `urls` directly:

```
url(r'^dashboard/cod/', cod_app.urls),
```

The `urls` property [returns a 3-tuple](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/2fa0e3b01ccf142b141e2dfaf14761a51dbf46b4/src/oscar/core/application.py#L124-L126), not a list of `urlpatterns`, and support for passing this to `include()` was dropped in Django 2.

Comment: Thanks this fixed it. I have been trying to get a way to connect with you from GitHub but I couldn’t get. Do you have a social media account that could ease chat?

Answer (score 1):

In `django2` its `path` for normal url and `re_path` for url using regex.

```
path('dashboard/cod/', include(cod_app.urls)),
```